# How Jersey Behaves on Not Mapped Exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

The `Jersey` [documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6352) explains how to convert an `Exception` to a `Response`, but it fails in detailing what will happen if my code throws an `Exception` that isn't mapped or derived from `WebApplicationException`.

[This link](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-en/cn/part1/chapter7/exception_handling.html) says:

> If the thrown exception is not handled by a mapper, it is propagated and handled by the container (i.e., servlet) JAX-RS is running within.

But this only explains how `JAX-RS 2.0` is supposed to behave in general terms and not how `Jersey`, which is the `container` in this case, is going to handle this `Exception`.

I know some people will just say `Well, why don't you try it out and see what happens?`... and the answer is: `Because I like to know the documentation and I try to avoid empirical results, since they can be contaminated with coincidences and exceptional cases`.

So, the question is:

**How `Jersey` deals with not mapped `Exceptions`, like `SQLException` or `IllegalArgumentException`? `Exceptions` that are thrown by one of my `Resources` and not handled by my code.**

Comment: `How Jersey deals with not mapped Exceptions, like SQLException or IllegalArgumentException?`, it doesn't. `ExceptionMapper` is an interface, you need to implement a class that implements that interface and make sure you provide cases for all exception types

Comment: What I mean is, "What will happen if my application throws an exception? Will it always be a 404 response? Will the response include the exception message?" there must have a common behavior for unhandled exceptions

Comment: ExceptionMapper is just a filter that accepts an Exception and returns a Response object, a common pattern is to use a switch/case with default to cover all exception types, for uncommon exceptions you can throw a 500 with a default message

Comment: I know what ExceptionMapper is and what it does, I just want to know what will happen if by some mistake I DON'T map something, what will happen if an exception slips.... For example, in a desktop application and uncaught exception will terminate the application, and what about Jersey, what's going to happen?

Comment: I have handled all those Exceptions in ExceptionMapper. But for unmapped URL, what should we do. For eg: If we have mapped for /services/*, we can handle those using ExceptionMapper. But, for /*, how can we handle these cases? All suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jersey is always deployed somewhere. Usually, it's a servlet container (in an application server or Tomcat for instance), but in Java SE only environment it can be for instance [Grizzly](https://javaee.github.io/grizzly/) or even [JDK HTTP server](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html). See [documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.javase) for deployment options.

What happens to exception uncaught (or thrown) by Jersey is up to this deployment environment. For instance, the servlet container usually catch the Exception, logs it and returns http status 500.

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense with what I am experiencing in my `GlassFish` local instance or my AWS Lambda instance! Many thanks